# How decision values are calculated in libsvm

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

Considering only linear kernel, how decision values are calculated in LIBSVM?

Generally, for a two class problem predictions are done based on sign(w*z+b) but in LIBSVM predictions are done based on sign(decision value).

I calculated w*z+b which is coming out to be different than decision value. 
Is there any relation between w*z+b and decision value.

Comment: Actually should be sum(w*z)+b, I hope you meant that.

Comment: yeah, I mean w*z as dot product of w and z.

Answer (score 0):

Decision function is exactly `<w, x> + b`, the only thing that might be missleading is that in matlab's structure `rho` is actualy `-b` (notice change of the sign) thus the decision function is `<w, x> - rho`